# How to detect an iPhone Volume Access in iOS Swift or Objective C

Tags: android, ios, swift, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have created one Unity basic game and take a build for Android and its working well but once I was trying to take build for Xcode then some issues are coming.
basically I was trying to take some task from Volume up and Volume down key in an iOS.

I will show Android Code, help me with iOS code.

```
    public int GetVolume()
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject context = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            AndroidJavaClass audioManagerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.media.AudioManager");
            AndroidJavaClass contextClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Context");
            int AudioManager_STREAM_MUSIC = audioManagerClass.GetStatic<int>("STREAM_MUSIC");
            string Context_AUDIO_SERVICE = contextClass.GetStatic<string>("AUDIO_SERVICE");
            AndroidJavaObject audioService = context.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getSystemService", Context_AUDIO_SERVICE);
            return audioService.Call<int>("getStreamVolume", AudioManager_STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Without showing at least some effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here. What have you tried to achieve your goals in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for Swift

```
let vol = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
```

The audio session can provide output volume (iOS >= 6.0).
In objective C :

float vol = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
NSLog(@"output volume: %1.2f dB", 20.f*log10f(vol+FLT_MIN));

Comment: Thanks for your response, @ajjjjjjjj

I am looking for C# code for implementing in my unity project.

Comment: WelCome. But you gave the tag of swift. that's why i answer

Comment: Can you help me to solve this, I need to do some functionality with iPhone Volume up and down button.